# Mounting /dev/sda3 but /etc/fstab not found?

Tags: arch-linux

I am currently trying to install Arch Linux and have run into a multitude of problems but my latest has really stumped me. I am currently trying to mount /dev/sda3 using the command:

```
$ mount /dev/sda3
```

When I execute above command, output says

`there is no /etc/fstab.`

I attempted to do

`genfstab -p /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab`

Output says:

`no such file or directory: /mnt/etc/fstab.`

What do you believe I did wrong?

Comment: `genfstab` said "no such file or directory"?  This question needs more detail and more precision.  As don_crissti pointed out, you misspelled `etc` in your question.  Did you also misspell it in the command line?  Please read [ask].

Comment: @depquid First off I can't add more precision due to the fact that that's all the information I got. Second I did not misspell it in command line. That is an extremely common mistake of mine and I check for that often. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: More precision would include making the quoted text in your question match what's on your console verbatim, character for character.

Comment: @depquid I understand that however you also talked about more detail. Can't give that either. And I gave as much precision as I could a two letter switch isn't that important.

Comment: @Griffen I respectfully disagree that "a two letter switch isn't that important".  Uncaught tyops can lead to all kinds of [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  Maybe it didn't matter for this question, but disregarding such mistakes is a bad habit to get in to.

Comment: @depquid Exactly. Not when asking a question. I didn't make that mistake in the terminal due to the fact that I double check everything I type there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to answer if you specified at which point in the installation process you are trying this. Assuming you are following the [arch install guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide/Installation), it looks like you just forgot to add the mountpoint to the `mount` command. try again like this:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
```

The other error is because there is no `/mnt/etc` directory so `genfstab` cannot create an `fstab` file in it.

Comment: Yes you were right I forgot to add it. And that was because I was getting desperate to fix it. Nice to see you again terdon. You're quite active and very knowledgeable. Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the mount command properly. You should use the command as follows:

```
$ mount /dev/sda3 /dir
```

where /dir is the mount point (which you can change as your wish). eg. /mnt or /media.

If only directory or device is given, for example:

```
$ mount /dir
```

then mount looks for a mountpoint and if not found then for a device in the /etc/fstab file.

So when you are executing

```
$ mount /dev/sda3
```

It is expecting /dev/sda3 in `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: Actually terdon got it the command is /mount /dev/sda3 /mnt