# I can't create fstab while installing arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mount

Firstly, I followed this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=METZCp_JCec) to install arch, but when I create `fstab` with `genfstab -p /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab` the error `No such file or directory` is shown. So I changed the code `genfstab -p /mnt >> /mnt/fstab`, the file was successfully created with the change, but I can't do the next installation step and how can I delete that created `fstab` file. I followed "[Mounting /dev/sda3 but /etc/fstab not found?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70523/mounting-dev-sda3-but-etc-fstab-not-found)" answers but it didn't work. Why is that `/etc/` path missing?

Comment: You say it did not work.  What happened when you tried?  And please include the output from running `mount` (with no options) in your question.

Comment: Use the [Arch Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners_Guide), not some random youtube tutorial that is more than likely outdated and full of erroneous and ill-advised suggestions...

Comment: Yeah when I followed the answers from that question, the result remained the same.

Comment: I typed mount /dev/sda2 /mnt, that line worked, then I ran genfstab, the error returned.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the root partition is mounted on `/mnt`, do not execute the command while inside `arch-chroot`.

```
exit
```

then issue:

```
genfstab /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

and then you can unmount it:

```
umount /mnt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably dead and gone but incase someone else runs into the same problem, I had this problem the other day ..

I simply typed " mkdir /mnt/etc " and then repeat the genfstab process.

It should automagically create the dir, but if it doesn't the above should work.

Comment: And did the ``/etc`` directory that you created manually get populated with all the files that belong there?

Comment: I've since learned that the problem was with the mount order

Answer (score 0):

By following the [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab); last paragraph reads:

*If for some reason the root partition has been improperly mounted read only, remount the root partition with read-write* access with the following command:*

`# mount -o remount,rw /`

Enjoy :)